# How to connect data source outlet to view controller that referenced in another storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, storyboard

I have a custom view controller designed in separate storyboard, it has a `dataSourceObj` outlet which is not connected:

**Custom view controller setup in storyboard**

[image]

```
class NavigationPanelController: NSViewController {

   @IBOutlet var navPanelView: NavigationPanelView!
   @IBOutlet var dataSourceObj: NSObject!
```

I want to use this controller in external storyboard and link some data source object there. I referenced my custom controller using 'Storyboard Reference':

**Referenced controller in external storyboard**

[image]

But I can't figure out how to make a data source outlet connection here, cause connections inspector tab displays 'Not applicable' for my storyboard reference.

Is there a proper way to connect some data source outlet?